# Apt-get update error Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I've just changed my os to Linux Mint 17, but I'm having some trouble when I try to run

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

[EDIT] Now I have the following errors:

```
Err http://extra.linuxmint.com qiana InRelease

Err http://extra.linuxmint.com qiana Release.gpg
Unable to resolve 'extra.linuxmint.com' 

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Unable to resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/qiana/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg Unable to resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/qiana/Release.gpg Unable to resolve 'packages.linuxmint.com'

W: Failed to download some index files. Been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

On the files under /etc/apt/source.list.d/ i have:
 official-package-repositories.list:
    # Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com qiana main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com qiana main #id:linuxmint_extra

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

getdeb.list:

```
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
```

Comment: Could you please provide your sources.list file under /etc/apt and/or the contents of the files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d?

Comment: I've just edited my post adding the info you asked

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message, but perhaps obscure. You are unable to resolve the various URLs listed. Probably because you have no Internet connection at all. Start with a ping to see if this is true:

ping kernel.org or any other well-known host like 8.8.8.8

If you get no ping, then try
dhclient eth0   ( assuming you are connected to eth0 ) to get a fresh IP address.

If you get a ping, then ping the URLs and try to see whats wrong. Wget is also a good tool, but ping is simpler.

Comment: I'm getting a ping, except in the URLs that I have the errors.

Comment: The first 4 are good URLs, so that narrows it down to some sort of DNS problem. Try nslookup to see if you get some info. Try it with a public DNS server like 8.8.8.8. Check your host file to be sure its not overriding DNS.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. i checked the urls and e.g.
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
just does not exist. everything with "inrelease" seems wrong, so the question is why the system tries to reach it. It's a bit confusing because
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty
indeed does exist..

Comment: You have solved the problem. In your browser go to ~trusty you will see "Release" (hint: when solving apt-get problems you can always just use the browser to see the files) I don't know what Mint expects, you might look for some documentation. Then edit sources.list.